# How long can a virus stay in the air for?

Tags: common-cold, airborne-transmission

For example, if a person with a cold goes into a small doctor's office and coughs, then they leave and 10 minutes later, you enter and breath the air in the room, can this make you sick?

Comment: Good question but why restrict it to viruses? Bacteria can be airborne too.

Comment: Hours and hours. https://www.livescience.com/35437-flu-particles-prevalent-in-air-public-places.html